# TypeScript init: error TS6053: File 'init.ts' not found

Tags: typescript, init, tsconfig

If I run `tsc init` in a empty directory, I get the error:

> error TS6053: File 'init.ts' not found

I have an understanding question: Shouldn't `tsc init` simply create a tsconfig.json file? If not, with which command can I create a tsconfig.json ?

p.s. Not a duplicate, other TS6053-posts are targeting another topics,..

Answer (score 34, accepted):

The command is wrong. You need to specify a flag:

```
tsc --init
```

Check out [this pull request](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/pull/4037) for more detail.

Comment: Oh, thank you! All other initialisers have the syntax `git init` or `npm init` and microsoft has 'tsc --init" :) But I see empirical knowledge makes you reckless,.. :)

Comment: Can I create a tsconfig.json with ""experimentalDecorators": true" in its initial creation? Is there a key for that?

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think that's currently possible, unless you change the defaults for the compiler globally.

Answer (score 4):

You probably have a typo :  type

```
tsc --init
```